# insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost on test ropsten server

Tags: solidity, nft, hardhat

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to create an NFT: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft/

I took a faucet here: https://faucet.metamask.io/

But when trying to mint the contract I get this error:

`λ npx hardhat --network ropsten run scripts/deploy.js Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost (error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code=INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=providers/5.5.3) at Logger.makeError (E:\chat\nft\my-nft\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:225:28) at Logger.throwError (E:\chat\nft\my-nft\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:237:20) at checkError (E:\chat\nft\my-nft\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:53:16) at E:\chat\nft\my-nft\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:215:24 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) { reason: 'insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost', code: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS', error: ProviderError: insufficient funds for gas * price + value at HttpProvider.request (E:\chat\nft\my-nft\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:49:19) at LocalAccountsProvider.request (E:\chat\nft\my-nft\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:182:36) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) at EthersProviderWrapper.send (E:\chat\nft\my-nft\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20), method: 'sendTransaction', transaction: undefined } I have tried to find on the net I do not understand why it does not work when I am on the ropsten test network.`

how i can solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Rija Cloud, could you find the solution? I have the same problem, also added a possible solution below. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same problem, and I reached the same point in that tutorial failing with the same exact message.

The problem on my side was the address was indeed without funds.
Go to this address to request funds from the faucet https://fauceth.komputing.org/ and enter your wallet address from metamask. if you have the browser extension you can find your correct address right there, see the following image:

[image: MetaMask Browser Extension]

You can also check on [Etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/) to validate if the funds are really there in your address.

Hope it helps [Rija Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7641375/rija-cloud) !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select rospten network in Alchemy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you update your `testnet` eg: from `rinkeby` to `kovan`, you also go ahead and get the new URL to reflect that change in network. If you done the URL will be pointing to the wrong `testnet`.